# Compare current value with last value sqlite to show in listview

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table in sqlite where weight is recorded.
Now I want to compare if the new value entered is < or == or > than the last value.
My problem is that I cannot compare "only" with the ultimate value, the comparison makes me all the records in the table.
This is my code

```
    private class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                           String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);}

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(super.getCount() - position - 1);}

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        String query = "SELECT nombre FROM miembros order by nombre DESC limit 1";
        SQLiteDatabase datos;
        datos = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase("DBMIEMBRO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor c = datos.rawQuery(query, null);

        int previous_day=0;
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            previous_day= (int) c.getLong(0)-1;
        }

        int present_day=(int) cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.MIEMBRO_NOMBRE));

        if (present_day > previous_day){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F0A1A1"));}//red
        if (present_day < previous_day){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AAF0A1"));}//green
        if (present_day == previous_day){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#18DBDB"));}//blue
```

[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: so what is the issue, it is not clear from question issue you are facing?

Comment: The issue is that I can not compare the new value with previous value, if you see a image i show my issue, the code just put me in red the biggest value (no more), I need put in red when the new value is bigger than the previous value. In other words, Actually i can get only one value in red, the biggest, i need red row alwais than new value is bigger than previous value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't write here some code right now, but here's an idea as I would implemented it:

I would added a trigger to the database and additional column with flag, for instance, less - 1, equal - 2, more - 3. With each new entry trigger would added a flag to this entry depending on comparison result between just added and previous weight values. Than all that you need in your code is to get flag from the database table and depending on it paint view with respective color.

I think the same approach may be used for row updating.

**Added trigger code:**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE weights (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT, weight INTEGER, flag INTEGER);

CREATE TRIGGER less_flag AFTER INSERT ON weights WHEN (SELECT weight FROM weights WHERE _id = last_insert_rowid()) < (SELECT weight FROM weights WHERE _id IN (select MAX(_id) from weights where _id <> last_insert_rowid()))     BEGIN update weights set flag = 0 where _id = last_insert_rowid(); END;

CREATE TRIGGER more_flag AFTER INSERT ON weights WHEN (SELECT weight FROM weights WHERE _id = last_insert_rowid()) > (SELECT weight FROM weights WHERE _id IN (select MAX(_id) from weights where _id <> last_insert_rowid()))     BEGIN update weights set flag = 1 where _id = last_insert_rowid(); END;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Here 1 - new value is bigger than previous. 0 - lower. Null - equal

Comment: WOW!!! Thanks, it works. Only i have a little issue, maybe it is easy but i dont find de key. When i wrote de code to paint each row, when the flag is 0 paint in green, 1 paint in red, if is equal paint in blue (all this works ok), but in the first time that insert data, by default it put in green (like a 0 flag) but really there is no flag because is the first data. I wrote this                                                         if (flag != 0 && flag != 1 && flag != 2){view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CE58F5"));} but does not work, paint green too

Comment: I need a little clarification: we have some weights dataset and the maximum value of this set is always red. What is the behavior when comes new entry with weight, which is bigger than current maximum value? 

Also there is another question: does first record contain always maximum value?

Comment: The goal is that when you put a higher value than before, turns red.
Now thanks to your answer this works well.
Now everything works as I wanted, I have only a small problem. The first value that you enter in the database, by default, it turns green and should not, should be in a new color, different from the others three, I have set up the code, but does not work if (flag! = 0 && flag! = 1 && flag! = 2) {// This should be the first day, as there is no flag in the database, but do not recognize}
I need to know what put to recognize that it is the first value entered in the database.

Comment: Here you go: 
`CREATE TRIGGER first_entry AFTER INSERT ON weights WHEN (select count(*) from weights) = 1 BEGIN update weights set flag = 2 where _id = last_insert_rowid(); END;`
Add it to other triggers. Here you can add new flag, for instance, 2, which corresponds to your other color (orange or yellow, I don't know).
Also you may not create this trigger, but just use conditional statement `if (cursor.getPosition() == 0) {//your code for first entry painting is here}`